# Canon m50 DISP icon

Tags: canon, display

Please help. When I am changing settings in photo mode (ISO for example) changes don't show in the display. In the bottom right corner, there is this icon. I do not want to reset all settings, tell me how to fix it

[image]

<sup>click for full size</sup>

Comment: What exposure mode are you using? Why did you crop out the left side of the screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

This is the "Exposure simulation" setting (on my EOS 70D, in the first menu with the "Camera back" icon). When you have "DISP" it is disabled.